# Temp agencies point distribution in “Welcome To...”

Tags: welcome-to

“Welcome To...” is a game that claims to support any number of players.  Despite this, there are some points which only are shared by a potentially few number of players who complete goals first or have the most of a particular effect used.

The player who has used the most temp agencies gets seven points.  The player who scored next highest gets four, and third gets one point.  To be eligible for points of this type one must have used at least one temp agency.  If there is a tie, players share points both getting the full number.

Herein lies the confusion.

Supposing we have five players, how many points does each player get in this scenario?

- A: 4 used, B: 4 used, C: 3 used, D: 3 used, E: 2 used

A and B would get seven points as they tied for first place for number of temp agencies used, there is no doubt about that.  Would C and D get four points as they have the second highest unique score and E get one point as the third highest unique score? Or would C and D get one point as there are two players who scored higher than them putting them as tying for "third place" and E gets no points?

Comment: Are you referring to [this game](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/233867/welcome)? If so, it would be helpful if you linked it because we don't all have our telepathy function enabled yet. Thanks!

Comment: @L.Scott FYI: Make sure you add a tag description after creating a tag that's only got a single use. The system automatically deletes tags after a short while if they've only got one question and no description. I've added one this time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[According to designer Benoit Turpin here](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1958110/article/28585899#28585899)
[image: forum post screengrab]

It will wind up being in my above hypothetical scenario that A and B both get seven points, C and D both get four points, and E gets one point.

The correct way to score this is to look at the list of number of temp agencies used ignoring duplicates, sort, and then all players who scored the top number get seven points each, all players who scored the second highest number (if it exists) get four points each, and all players who scored the third highest number (if it exists) get one point each, all of this subject to the constraint that they must have used at least one temp agency to be eligible for points of this type in the first place.